# Выставления приложения в Play Market

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, app

Сделал свое первое приложения. Точно помню как ввел при создании проекта имя пакета com.webhost.fariz. Вроде бы все окей но при попытки выставить в плей маркете первую рабочую версию после оброботки файла апк выдает что имя пакета com.example и оно недопустимо. Что я мог сделать не правильно? может кто знает по опыту

Comment: Ну в самом проекте в app бывает имя пакета, там что написано?

Comment: В `build.gradle`(module) у Вас задан `applicationId 'com.webhost.fariz'`?

Comment: у меня также было..я пересоздавал проект

Comment: везде там название моего пакета но build.gradle не смотрел